# Image of separable complete metric space is measurable

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I'm wondering about the following problem;

suppose that $ \mu $ is a finite Borel measure on a separable metric space $ X $. Now, suppose we have a continuous map $ f: F \rightarrow X $ from a separable, complete metric space $ F $ to $ X $. My aim is to prove that $ f(F) $ is $ \mu $-measurable.

I was trying to work around the following theorem:

Suppose we have a complete, separable metric space $ X $ with Borel measure $ \mu $. Then for every subset $ E \subset X$ of finite measure and $ \varepsilon > 0 $ there exists a compact $ K \subset E $ such that $ \mu(E \setminus K)  < \varepsilon$.

I'm not sure that this can be applied directly, but somehow we might be able to use the construction of $ K $. We pick closed $ F \subset E $ with $ \mu(E \setminus F) < \varepsilon/2 $ and inductively construct a sequence of closed $ F_i $ such that $ \mu(F_i \setminus F_{i+1}) \leq \varepsilon/2^i $ and every $ F_i $ can be covered by a finite number of balls of diameter $ \leq 1/i $. The intersection then is the $ K $ we're looking for.

I'm not quite sure how to run this sort of argument, using also continuity of $ f $. I would appreciate some hints

**Edit** I made an error; the space $ X $ is not necessarily complete, but it is separable

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that continuous functions are borel-measurable?

Comment: Of course I am. Does this help in some obvious way I can't see yet?

Comment: not sure anymore, I just realized that what I was thinking was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a few more details to Henno's excellent hint.

The identity map $X\overset{\text{id}}{\to} X$ lifts to 
an isometry $X\overset{i}{\to} \bar X$, from $X$ into the completion $\bar X$ of $X$.

If $C$ is a countable dense subset of $X$, then since $i(X)$ is dense in $\bar X$,  the countable set $i(C)$ is dense in $\bar X$. That is, $\bar X$ is a Polish space.

Now the composition $F \overset{f}{\to}X\overset{i}{\to}\bar X$ is a continuous
 mapping of $F$ into $\bar X$ so that the image $i(f(F))$ is universally measurable in $\bar X$ (as mentioned in Henno's answer).

Since $i$ is one to one, we have $i^{-1}(i(f(F)))=f(F).$ Also since $i$ is continuous, it is also a Borel measurable map $(X,{\cal{B}})\overset{i}{\to} (\bar X,\bar{\cal{B}})$ and therefore 
$(X,{\cal{B}}^u)\overset{i}{\to} (\bar X,\bar{\cal{B}}^u)$ is also measurable
 for the universal completions. It follows that $f(F)\in{\cal B}^u,$ that is, 
$f(F)$ is universally measurable in $X.$

Answer (score 1):

$f[F]$ is a so-called [analytic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set), which is [universally measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set).

But there might be a more elementary approach.

Comment: I'm sorry, my first post was not right. The space $ X $ need not be Polish

Comment: Embedding $X$ in its completion might help. Not sure. (It's late and I'm off to bed.) Then we have an analytic set in the completion, and we can extend the measure to the completion in the obvious way, maybe..